# A model of pillows

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

(The same system with slightly different questions has been asked in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615558/euler-lagrange-with-derivative-of-multipliers/4619448#4619448).)

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be some simply connected planar domain. We seek for a mapping $\mathbf{r}:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that

a) The lengths of all axes-aligned segments remain unchanged,

b) The boundary remains planar, i.e, $\mathbf{r}|_{\partial \Omega}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$,

c) The volume between the plane and the surface is maximal.

Writing $\mathbf{r}=\left(u(x,y),v(x,y),w(x,y) \right)$, being $(x,y)$ rectangular coordinates on $\Omega$, the 1st condition is expressed as

\begin{align}
(u_x)^2+(v_x)^2+(w_x)^2&=1\\
(u_y)^2+(v_y)^2+(w_y)^2&=1,
\tag{*}
\end{align}

while

\begin{align}
w\left(\partial \Omega\right)=0
\tag{**}
\end{align}

for the 2nd condition, and the functional

\begin{align}
V\left[u(x,y),v(x,y),w(x,y)\right]=\int_\Omega dxdy\:\left(u_x v_y-u_y v_x\right)w,
\tag{***}
\end{align}

is to be maximized to satisfy the 3rd condition. Introducing the multipliers $\lambda_1=\lambda_1(x,y)$ and $\lambda_2=\lambda_2(x,y)$ to enforce the constraints, we find the Euler-Lagrange equations

\begin{align}
0&=u_x v_y-u_y v_x+\left(\lambda_1 w_x \right)_x+\left(\lambda_2 w_y \right)_y\\
0&=-\left(wv_y-\lambda_1 u_x\right)_x+\left(wv_x+\lambda_2 u_y\right)_y\\
0&=\left(wu_y+\lambda_1 v_x\right)_x-\left(w u_x-\lambda_2 v_y\right)_y.
\end{align}

The boundary conditions of $u$ and $v$ are free, meaning that among all the possible conditions we seek for the ones that maximize $V$ (for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ as well).

> Is the problem well-posed? What are the conditions for the existence of a (unique?) maximizer? Is it possible to come up with the maximizing boundary conditions of $u,\:v,\: \lambda_1,\:\lambda_2$? Is there a general protocol to eliminate the multipliers in this kind of problems?

I suspect the existence of a maximizer can be safely established. The picture below shows a numerical simulation for $\Omega$ a unit square.

[image]

Comment: I see.  A pride of lions, a murder of crows, an exaltation of larks, a model of pillows.

Comment: @WillJagy, an overflow of mathematicians?

Comment: Similar questions were studied in Paulsen, What is the shape of a mylar balloon?, Amer. Math. Monthly 101 (1994) and Pak, Schlenker, Profiles of inflated surfaces, Journal of Nonlinear Mathematical Physics, Volume 17, 2010 - Issue 2

Comment: @LSpice  here's a real one, based on observed behavior:  a *wedge* of swans

Comment: Is there a physical unit to measure squishiness or sponginess? That's something I've wondered and was reminded of by this question.

Comment: I don't know how related this is, but when I saw the pillow I was reminded of Igor Pak's article ["Inflating Polyhedral Surfaces"](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/pillow4.pdf).

Comment: What volume does your numerical simulation give?

Comment: @MattF. $0.99\pm 0.02$. In the teabag problem it is $0.23/2$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_bag_problem)

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you. Pak considers submetric mappings, meaning that the lengths of the geodesics are smaller than the lengths of their corresponding pre-images . Here we require that not the geodesics but some other curves (the ones aligned with the axes, that is, the warp and weft ) preserve their lengths. In that sense this mapping is less constrained.

Comment: That number doesn’t seem right — a hemisphere with surface area $1$ has volume $(3\sqrt{2\pi})^{-1}\sim .133$, and isn’t that maximal for any volume with unit surface area?

Comment: @MattF. This is for unit length edges. The corresponding sphere to compare would have radius 1/2 so the volume is $\pi/6\approx 0.5$, and we consider only half of it so the bound is $0.25$.

Comment: What happens if $\Omega$ is a disk? Do you have an idea of the answer in this case?

Comment: Unless I miss something, do you mean the uniqueness of the maximizer (if it exists) is up to some constant? E.g. if $(u,v,w)$ is a maximizer, so it is with $(u+a,v+b,w)$ for any reals $a,b$. Can you please explain why this translation does not change your problem?